# Background video animates on scrolling frustration

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate-on-scroll

I'm about to make a website that I want to have a video background that advances only on page scrolling. I had found a solution at the start of the year but no matter how much I search or keyword searches for it again and failed miserably.

I remember it involved creation in After Effects and saving each frame as jpg, and how to code it in html5/css/js.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: (1) Why not check your browser history? (2) So it's not a video background, more a series of static images?

Comment: You might find these video tutorials useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLUJ9VNzZXo , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hY1a94niwpY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making a div at top as bound element to check the distance when scrolling.

inside function `scrollVideo` i am checking if the video has played before.

using `getBoundingClientRect().top`:which returns value of a DOMRect object which is the smallest rectangle which contains the entire element, including its padding and border-width.[Read More About it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

getting `percentScrolled` with `(window.scrollY - distanceFromTop)` / `(bound.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight)`. it may return a float value i.e. decimals. that's why i am performing math.min & math.max on it.
getting `currenTime` with `video.duration * percentScrolled` & requesting animation on it.

NOTE* video should be in `webm` format. i have'nt tested it in any other format.

[Actual Video Link](https://cdn.ananaspizza.de/file/malte-image-store/v9-webm.webm)

```js
const registerVideo = (bound, video) => {
  bound = document.querySelector(bound);
  video = document.querySelector(video);
  const scrollVideo = () => {
    if (video.duration) {
      const distanceFromTop = window.scrollY + bound.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      const rawPercentScrolled = (window.scrollY - distanceFromTop) / (bound.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight);
      const percentScrolled = Math.min(Math.max(rawPercentScrolled, 0), 1);

      video.currentTime = video.duration * percentScrolled;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(scrollVideo);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(scrollVideo);
}


registerVideo("#bound", "#bound video");
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

#bound {
  background: #d0d8db;
}

.scroll-bound {
  height: 500vh;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

video {
  width: 80%;
}


}
```

```html
<div id="bound" class="scroll-bound">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Video on Scroll</p>
    <video width="600" muted preload>
                <source src="https://cdn.ananaspizza.de/file/malte-image-store/v9-webm.webm" type="video/webm">
                <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
      </video>
  </div>
</div>
```